# Hiding minimap in VS Code leaves behind a big "gap"

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I hide the minimap in VS Code, the text wraps too early for my liking - acting as if the minimap was still present, but just not visible. Any way to change this? Thanks!

Comment: is it a virtual wrap (no line number) or do you get a new line number

Comment: no new line number...